# where to use route-name of routing in aspnet mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i'm new to routing in aspnet mvc.. i have following code: 
Action Controller

```
public ActionResult SchoolIndex()
{
    return View(SchoolRepository.GetAllSchools());
}
```

here is the routing

```
routes.MapRoute(
"School",                                              // Route name
"{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
new { controller = "School", action = "SchoolIndex", id = "" } ); // Parameter defaults
```

when i enter "localhost/school" in addressbar, it is giving 404 error instead it should route to my "schoolIndex" action

i have given route-name as "School" where it is used ?

Comment: Check if your controller name is 'SchoolController' or not

Comment: yes the controller name is "schoolcontroller"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify a route name in a URI, ever.

Route names are for, e.g., `Html.RouteLink()`. `RouteLink` allows you to specify exactly the route you want, even if it's not the first matching route for the arguments you pass.

URIs are matched in order. The first matching route wins.

Read [my post on routing](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/03/18/38085/) for much more detail.