# Asp.net MVC 3 routing issue with UrlHelper.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have caught in a issue related to how helper Action method and routing work. I have created a helper method to create search links

```
public static string SearchLink(this System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper helper, string key, string loc, int p)
{
    key = Tools.GetLinkRewrite(key.Trim().ToLower());
    loc = Tools.GetLinkRewrite(loc.Trim().ToLower());

    string url = "";

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(key) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(loc))
    {
        if (p > 0)
            url = helper.Action("Index", "Search", new { keyword = key, location = loc, page = p });
        else
            url = helper.Action("Index", "Search", new { keyword = key, location = loc });
    }else
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
    {
        if (p > 0)
            url = helper.Action("Index", "Search", new { keyword = key, page = p });
        else
            url = helper.Action("Index", "Search", new { keyword = key });
    }else
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(loc))
    {
        if (p > 0)
            url = helper.Action("Index", "Search", new { location = loc, page = p });
        else
            url = helper.Action("Index", "Search", new { location = loc });
    }else
    url = helper.Action("Index", "Search");

    return url.Replace("%20","+");
}
```

And here is my routing

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Search",
            "{keyword}-jobs-in-{location}",
            new { controller = "Search", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Searchlocation",
            "jobs-in-{location}",
            new { controller = "Search", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Searchkeyword",
            "{keyword}-jobs",
            new { controller = "Search", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Now when I call SearchLink from any action as with parameters eq. Url.SearchLink("asp.net", "", 0), it give me correct url as /asp.net-jobs

But if call same method from Index action of SearchController with same parameters it give me /asp.net-jobs-in-

Although I can achieve correct behavior(thank Craig for giving [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865312/where-to-use-route-name-of-routing-in-aspnet-mvc/2865688#2865688)) by using RouteUrl instead of Action in above extension method, But I want to understand why it's happing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the problem in your route definition?
The way they are defined now, I couldn't get it to work.
Since you don't have a {controller} nor {action} placeholder defined for them, it will always user the SearchController and it's method Index; yet you define other actions in you helper function (Search, Searchkeyword and Searchlocation). When I changed the routes accordingly, I had no problem at all @Url.SearchLink("key1", "",0) return /key1-jobs throughout my entire app..

Comment: Yes, I want to call Index action of SearchController for 3 urls. I have only 2 action in SearchController "Index" and "RecentSearch". On recentsearch view url generated are correct for all combination of keyword and location. on Index view I am showing some similar search links that are not generated correctly using same helper method.

Comment: What other routes did or do you have registered? I seem to have trouble to make this work. If I just use the routes you have, and I browse to localhost/asp.net-jobs  (the only way to make it work)  the `url = helper.Action("Searchkeyword", new { keyword = key });` returns null upon calling `Url.Searchlink("myKey","",0)` reason for this is that there's no action with the name *Searchkeyword* in the SearchController. The first parameter of Url.Action is the name of an action, not the name of route. So I am curious how this works for you....

Comment: Oh, I am really sorry. I have updated the extension method in my question. I messed up the function code while making fixes and posting on SO. If you want I can send you a sample project code showing problem.